# Aggregate one of the fields in linq to sql

Tags: sql, linq, aggregate

I have a table with diffrent fields like

table leg:

```
    leg.city1 as string
```

I want to query a database and put this field from diffrent records in one string

```
dim report = (From x In DataBase.legs
Select x.city1)aggregate(Function(p) p))
```

I know my code is wrong

any help?

Answer (score 2):

Use string concatenation with `+`:

```
dim report = (From x In DataBase.legs
              Select x.city1 + x.city2 + x.city3)
```

Comment: sorry, i asked it wrong, i have another problem, i want to accumulate one field from diffrent records. i'm gonna fix the question. any way tnx for answer.